# is ‘fine’ in the sense ‘of very good quality’ gradable?

Tags: grammar, comparative-degree

fine in the sense *of very good quality * seems somewhat an abosulte adjective. Since absolute adjectives are not gradable, I am wondering whether this principle applies to fine in the sense ‘of very good quality’ as well?

p.s. why fine seems an absolute adj. to me:
let’s consider the following etym. info of fine
from old French fin ‘end’, cognate with Eng. finish
These etym. info brings me such a semantic impression as ‘too good to be improved further’ or ‘so good as cannot be better’, whence I feel fine much like an ‘absolute adjective’ such as superior.

Answer (score 1):

**"fine quality"** > **"a very fine quality"** > **"the finest quality"**: all forms are usable